# NetLogo: Subtract One Patch-set From Another

Tags: netlogo

Im trying to create a `patch-set` without having to define each patch in the list individually. However, in order to do this I need to subtract one `patch-set` from another. In my model, `patches own` O2. I have a few selected patches in which their value for O2 should not change. I would like to create a `patch-set` for patches with `pxcor = max-pxcor` but exclude these patches that should hold O2 constant. I have tried subtracting the patch-sets, but got an error message saying `-expected this input to be a number, but got a patch agentset instead.` I have also tried setting the patch-set as lists, and then using the `remove` command to modify the list. However, this then presents the problem when I `ask` the list to perform something, I get the error `ASK expected an agent or agentset, but got a list instead`.

Below is the relevant code where I try to build the patch-set:

```
set NS1 (patch-set patch -8 -5 6 patch -8 -5 -5 patch -8 6 6 patch -8 6 -5  patch 8 -5 6 patch 8 -5 -5 patch 8 6 6 patch 8 6 -5) 
set NS2 (patch-set patch -8 0 6 patch -8 0 -5 patch 8 0 6 patch 8 0 -5  )  
set NS3 (patch-set patch -4 -5 6 patch -4 -5 -5 patch 4 -5 6 patch 4 -5 -5 patch -4 6 6 patch -4 6 -5 patch 4 6 6 patch 4 6 -5) 
set NS4 (patch-set patch -4 0 6 patch -4 0 -5 patch 4 0 6 patch 4 0 -5 )  
set NS5 (patch-set patch -8 0 0 patch 8 0 0 )                 
set NS6 (patch-set patch -8 -5 0 patch -8 6 0 patch 8 -5 0 patch 8 6 0 )      
set NS7 (patch-set patch -4 -5 0 patch -4 6 0 patch 4 -5 0 patch 4 6 0   )   
set NS8 (patch-set patch 0 0 6 patch 0 0 -5 )             
set NS9 (patch-set patch 0 -5 6 patch 0 -5 -5 patch 0 6 6 patch 0 6 -5)
set NS10 (patch-set patch 0 -5 0 patch 0 6 0 )             
set NS11 patch 0 0 0                          
set NS12 (patch-set patch -4 0 0 patch 4 0 0 )             

set FEMnodes (sentence NS1 NS2 NS3 NS4 NS5 NS6 NS7 NS8 NS9 NS10 NS11 NS12)  
set Xmaxmin (list (patch-set patches with [ pxcor = min-pxcor] patches with [ pxcor = max-pxcor]))
set lateral remove FEMnodes Xmaxmin
set Ymaxmin (list (patch-set patches with [ pycor = min-pycor ] patches with [ pycor = max-pycor ]))
set FB remove FEMnodes Ymaxmin
set Zmaxmin (list (patch-set patches with [ pzcor = min-pzcor ] patches with [ pzcor = max-pzcor ]))
set TP remove FEMnodes Zmaxmin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `FEMnodes` contains the patches with the constant O2, correct? If so, you can do the following:

```
patches with [ pxcor = max-pxcor and not member? self FEMnodes ]
```

to get all patches with `pxcor = max-pxcor` that are not in `FEMnodes`.

So, I think you want `Xmaxmin` to actually be defined as follows:

```
set Xmaxmin patches with [ (pxcor = min-pxcor or pxcor = max-pxcor) and not member? self FEMnodes ]
```

For general patch-set difference, you can use:

```
to-report patch-set-difference [ set1 set2 ]
  report set1 with [ not member? self set2 ]
end
```

but I think the definition of `Xmaxmin` I gave is more the strategy you'll want to use.